# Windows laptop losing connection to Airport Express

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, airport-extreme

I have a Windows 7 laptop connecting through wifi to an Airport Extreme router at work. When I leave work in the evening with my hibernating laptop and come back the following morning, it's unable to connect to the same wifi network. The laptop sees the network, it tries to connect to it, but eventually fails with a generic "unable to connect" dialog.

Disabling and enabling the network device has no effect.
Rebooting the laptop has no effect.
After rebooting the Airport, the laptop is able to connect.

I have a wifi network at home and have no problems whatsoever. Then again, all the other computers at work don't have any problem connecting to the router. AFAIK both networks are 802.11a/b/g/n without any restrictions.

There's another Airport Extreme router at work and the laptop doesn't experience this problem. Laptop connects immediately. If laptop is connected to 2nd router (good one) and I walk to the 1st router (bad one), laptop loses connection.

Airport Extreme specs:
Version 7.6.4
Model no A1408  5th generation

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect from the network, suspend the laptop, then attempt to connect to the network.  This can be tested currently.

Comment: I have tried both sleep mode and hibernate mode and the laptop was able to reconnect without any problem.

Comment: What 802.11 mode is both networks?  Update your question with this information.

Comment: How would I check this?

Comment: For the office network as the Administrator of the network.  For your home network log into the configuration of the access point and check.

Comment: Both home and work networks are 802.11 a/b/g/n without any restrictions.

Comment: Hi @Spiff, nice username. :-) What is the exact model of AirPort Extreme? What firmware version is it running? Use the AirPort Utility in OS X or iOS (or even the older one for Windows) to find out.

Comment: Hehe thx Spiff :) I just edited the question to include the information you requested.

Answer (score 0):

We sidestepped the problem by switching the two routers. Not really a solution per se, but good enough for now.